# Is there a way to upload files from Oracle Apex to sharepoint

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, oracle-apex, sharepoint-online

I wanted to use Oracle-APEX application as a client application. When users upload files from this application. It calls a web service and transfer files to SharePoint online document library. Is there a way to do this?

I'm trying to make use of the code on Microsoft. Am I on the right track?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery

I saved my files as blob type in oracle database. Is it possible to upload these fiels from oracle to sharepoint online? Am I on the right track?

Comment: This came up on a google search for "oracle apex sharepoint" http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2014/10/ms-sharepoint-and-oracle-apex.html